# Calculating $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty (2+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{3}{k+1})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I come to this limit:

$$\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \left(2+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{3}{k+1}\right)$$

but I don't know how to calculate it.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: The sum diverges because of (probably) the first divergence test you learnt in your course.

Comment: Do the terms tend to $0$?

Comment: yes i got it now. it diverges.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed in the problem the series has flaws, namely, it diverges as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Consider the finite sum 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{1}{k} - \frac{3}{k+1} \right) 
\end{align}
which is evaluated as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{1}{k} - \frac{3}{k+1} \right) = 2n - 2H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} + 3,
\end{align}
where $H_{n}$ is the Harmonic number. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ both $n$ and $H_{n}$ tend to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

When considering $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$, if $a_n$ *does not* go to $0$, then the series diverges.